# interface as generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I was researching at a fragment of someone else's code and something seemed curious to me.(just because I'm not familiar with the с# language)

there is an interface with the following method

```
   internal interface IPlayer
    {
        List<int> MakeMove(List<int> Gameboard, int Player);
    }
```

then a list is created in one of the classes and the interface is used there as a generic

```
    public List<IPlayer> AI_Players = new List<IPlayer> { };
. . .

    public void AIMove(int AI_Type)
    {
        Gameboard = AI_Players[AI_Type].MakeMove(Gameboard, Currentplayer);
    }
```

Can you please explain what is a list with interfaces as a generic?I understand what, for example, a list with an int generic is..but..what does this list store?

and what is  **[AI_Type]** in this line?

```
Gameboard = AI_Players[AI_Type].MakeMove(Gameboard, Currentplayer);
```

Comment: _"what is `[AI_Type]`"_ That's an indexer. `AI_Type` will be an integer giving the position in the list to access.

Comment: `AI_Type` is the parameter, and the `[]` is just the list indexer.

Comment: The `AI_Players` List is a list of object references but each object in that list supports the `IPlayer` interface, and is referred to by that interface.

Comment: @Wyck  okay, thanks .and what would be the difference if the name of the class that implements this interface was written there as a generic?

Comment: I assume you would have something that looks like `public List<T> AI_Players = new List<T> { };`    But it can't be **completely** generic because `AI_Player[AI_Type]` is of type `T` but it must also support the `.MakeMove` method.  So there would be a constraint that whatever interface `T` is would need to be derived from some other interface that supports `.MakeMove`  Like an `IMoveMaker` or something then the generic would be constrained with `where T: IMoveMaker` and `T` could be anything that derives from `IMoveMaker`.

Answer (score 2):

In short, this means that the list can only contain objects that implement this interface. So the individual elements of the list can be different concrete classes, but each of these classes must implement the interface.

Comment: well, thank you. For example, if I have one class that implements this interface, then there would be no difference if I wrote as a generic the name of the class that implements this interface, right?

Comment: Design aspects aside, as long as it will remain just a single class, then it won't really make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

> AI_Players[AI_Type]

`AI_Type` would be an *index*. And it might be argued that a better name would be *aiPlayerIndex*, or that the list should be renamed to *aiPlayerTypes*;

> what does this list store?

It stores references to objects, where the type of reference is `IPlayer`

> Can you please explain what is a list with interfaces as a generic?

Interfaces is a kind of type, just like a int or a string is a type. A list can contain values of any type, int, string, IPlayer or any other type.

Note that the *objects* in the list might be of a different type than the *reference*. It is perfectly fine to have a list of *IPlayer* that contains both objects of *AIPlayer* and *HumanPlayer*.